# Compact embedding of anisotropic Sobolev space

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, compactness, embeddings

I am wondering if the embedding from $W^{2,1}_p(\Omega \times [0,T])$ to $C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}(\Omega \times [0,T])$ is compact, for some suitable domain, $p$ and $\alpha$. I have found some results. I think it is at least continuous, we can check Chapter 1.4 in "Elliptic & Parabolic Equations" by Zhuoqun Wu, Jingxue Yin and Chunpeng Wang. Does anyone have the compactness result?

Comment: Once it is continuous for some $\alpha$ it is compact for any $\beta<\alpha$, using the compactness of the embeding between Holder spaces.

Comment: So bad that I can not observe from this. Thank you so much!